# C++ Implementing a pure virtual function over a template

Tags: c++, function, templates, abstract

I am trying to implement an abstract class (ElementHolder) over a Template (TElementHolder). The function `virtual T* Fun2()` seems to work fine but the function `virtual void Fun(T* element);` creates the following compile error:

```
source>:60:23: error: cannot declare variable 'fireHolder' to be of abstract type 'FireElementHolder'
   60 |     FireElementHolder fireHolder;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:51:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'FireElementHolder':
   51 | class FireElementHolder : public TElementHolder<Fire>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:22: note:     'virtual void ElementHolder::Fun(Element*)'
   22 |         virtual void Fun(Element* element) = 0;
      |
```

Can someone explain to me why the two functions create different results?
And if I can make this work somehow?

I am not sure if *Implementing a pure virtual function over a template* is the correct way of saying what I am doing here.

source: https://godbolt.org/z/qEYdrYfYa

```
#include <iostream>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Element
{
    public:
        virtual ~Element() {}
        virtual void Fun() = 0;
};
class Fire : public Element
{
    public:
        ~Fire() {}
        void Fun() { std::cout << "Fire" << std::endl; }
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ElementHolder
{
    public:
        virtual ~ElementHolder() {}

        virtual void Fun(Element* element) = 0;
        virtual Element* Fun2() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class TElementHolder : public ElementHolder
{
    public:
        virtual ~TElementHolder();

        virtual void Fun(T* element);
        virtual T* Fun2();
};
template<class T>
TElementHolder<T>::~TElementHolder() {}

template<class T>
void TElementHolder<T>::Fun(T* element)
{
    element->Fun();
}

template<class T>
T* TElementHolder<T>::Fun2()
{    
    std::cout << "Hello Fun2" << std::endl;
    return new T();
}

class FireElementHolder : public TElementHolder<Fire>
{

};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int main()
{
    FireElementHolder fireHolder;
    auto instance = fireHolder.Fun2();
    fireHolder.Fun(instance);
    instance->Fun();
}
```

Comment: you changed the parameter type, hence the method is not overriden. `Element*` -> `T*` where `T == Fire`

Comment: Can you explain what is the aim of all this? The simple fix is to use the right argument type, but not sure if thats what you want

Comment: Use [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) when you override a base class `virtual` function. At least then the compiler will tell you if there is a problem, rather than finding out during runtime.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/d3M6edErE

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So it works for return types but not for parameters?
I wanted to figure out if I can use Templates to implement an abstract class. The ElementHolder is supposed to be used as a restriction of what "T" can be in the derived classes of TElementHolder. virtual T* Fun2() works fine in my compiler or at least I get the result I want.

Comment: Method overloading depends only on arguments, not on the return type. So child `Fire2()` overrides parent `Fire2()`, but `Fun(Element*)` and `Fun(T*)` are completely different methods.
The former is still pure virtual.

Comment: you stuffed too much things together. you can get the same effects without any template: https://godbolt.org/z/7v94db4rW

Comment: Also, deriving a template class from a normal one is completely backwards. What types do you expect to pass as `<T>`?

Comment: I suspect that [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) is proper solution for this issue

Comment: Usually I choose either inheritance (dynamic polymorphism) or I use (meta)template programming (static polymorphism). Mixing them usually doesn't work well.

Comment: @PepijnKramer double dispatch is easier when templates are used: https://godbolt.org/z/63T1jTYd1 so it depends on a case.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I believe now that my approach to the problem was wrong initially.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-known problem with your design.

You have two parallel class hierarchies, `Element`s and `ElelementHolder`s. You want each concrete `ElementHolder`  to accept a pointer or reference to a corresponding `Element`. So you add a pure virtual function to the base class

```
class ElementHolder {
   virtual void Fun(Element* element) = 0;
```

and override it in each derived class (I de-templatized your hierarchy for ease of exposition, there is a `T` instead of `Fire` in your code, but it doesn't really affect anything):

```
class FireHolder : public ElementHolder {
   virtual void Fun(Fire* fire) { ... }
```

Which is a very natural and sensible choice.

Except that it doesn't work at all, because `void Fun(Fire* fire)` doesn't override `void Fun(Element* element)`. They are completely independent functions.

Now how do you solve this problem? There are two very different ways.

1. Get rid of `ElementHolder::Fun` altogether.
2. Change `void Fun(Fire* fire)` to `void Fun(Element* fire)`. Cast `fire` to `Fire*` inside.

How does one cope without `ElementHolder::Fun`? Simply, just don't call it ;) You cannot safely use it anyway. The signature `Fun(Element*)` says that *any* element can be passed. In fact you can only pass `Fire*` to a `FireHolder`, and any other element is an error (so the signature lies---not a good idea). If you only have an `ElementHolder` and an `Element *`, there is no guarantee you can call `Fun`.

If you absolutely must call `ElementHolder::Fun`, then #2 is your only option.